# JavaScript remove all text before a character

Tags: javascript, email

im builing a mail parser for my work, i've got it working form sending the mail to getting it on the screen, but now i would like to remove the oldest mail, the one thats on the top. my idee is that i make a var and add the string to it then remove everything untill the first ~ on a click of a button. and have it so i can use the same button to remove the oldest mail everytime. can anyone help me realize this?

Gr. Ruben

edit:

HTML:

## First Mail__________~second mail________~

JavaScript:

```
var str = document.getElementByTagName("h1")
mail = str.lastIndexOf('~') + 1;
```

and then change the  tag to the value of the string

Comment: Please be more specific and also if u can give an example.

Comment: if you are just using ~ as a separator then i am afraid that it wont everytime. It may happen that people include ~ sign in the email and then your logic will fail.

Comment: no, i've configured it to add a _______~ to the end of every mail

Comment: if u want to remove first mail then why u use lastIndexOf

Comment: sorry typie just str.indexOf("~") + 1;

Comment: So of what i understand. You need to remove First Mail__________~ and then just show this second mail________~ right?

Comment: yeah, and then if you click the button (or other event) do it for the next mail

Comment: Are you using jQuery or you want to it using pure js?

Comment: i can use both jQuery and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing the first mail you can do this.

```
var truncateEmail = function(mailDom){
     var text = mailDom.text(),
        truncatedEmail = text.substr((text.indexOf("__~") + 3));
     return truncatedEmail;
}
// removing email on click of a button

$("#truncate-btn").on("click",function(){
   $("#mail1").html(truncateEmail($("#mail1")));
})
```

See if this what you need.

Comment: Sorry but as you might know I'm not that experienced so can you Mabey get it working in a jsfiddle

Comment: No problem. I m glad i could help you. Let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: i've got one more question, how do i do it if i have all thing incomming mails in a external html file and i load them in using a iframe with no borders

Comment: I think you should get the mails using websockets or ajax. and then load them in ur live page. Loading stuff in iframe is not a good idea as you wont ve much command over that.

Comment: Can you do that for me to

Comment: Sorry could you Mabey put that in a js fiddle for me to, i really don't know anything in Ajax or websocket

Comment: Its impossible to make a working fiddle for ajax and websocket. it needs server side connections. how do u get ur incomming mails? what server side u r using?

Comment: I'm using exchange over srv6.domain.nl